# How to apply the concept of counting occurrences on strings variables in C++

Tags: c++, counting

following program ca calculate the frequency of ints in an array
how to apply this concept on string variable because a string is also an array on the back end

```
using namespace std;
int counter[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int arr [9][9],x;
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    cout<<"enter the array  \n";
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
            arr[i][j]=rand()%10;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }


    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
            counter[arr[i][j]]++;

        }
    }

    for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
          cout<<j<<" : "<<  counter[j]<<endl;

        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A number is a series of items from the alphabet [0..9]. A string is a series of items from a slightly larger alphabet. Assuming your string is regular ASCII, you could use [0..127] as your alphabet. This will still include some characters that are not printable (all <32, for example), but should suffice for your example.

Comment: Joke: once you're done with computing `char` frequencies on a `std::string`, you can basically do it on any type, like `std::basic_string<int>` :D

Comment: Is your aim to count the occurrences of different strings, or of characters within a single string?

Comment: i want to count the frequency of each individual character in a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how one can count occurrences of anything from anything:

#### Code

```
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

template<class InputIt>
auto
occurrences(InputIt begin, InputIt end)
{
    std::map<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type, std::size_t> result;
    std::for_each(begin, end, [&result](auto const& item){ ++result[item]; });
    return result;
}
```

#### Usage

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto text = std::string{"Hello, World!"};
    auto occ = occurrences(begin(text), end(text));
    std::cout << occ['l'] << '\n'; // outputs 3
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3eec0f4159b151b8)

#### Explanation

```
template<class InputIt>
```

This is a generic (template) function iterating over any input iterator.

```
auto
```

Its return type is inferred from its implementation. Spoiler alert: it is a `std::map` of (value counter, occurrence of this value).

```
occurrences(InputIt begin, InputIt end)
```

`occurrences` is called with a couple of iterators defining a range, generally calling `begin(C)` and `end(C)` on your container `C`.

```
std::for_each(begin, end, //...
```

For each element in the range...

```
[&result](auto const& item){ //...
```

...execute the following treatment...

```
++result[item]; });
```

...increment the occurrence count for the value `item`, starting with zero if its the first.

This is not an *efficient* implementation since it copies the values it counts. For integers, characters, *etc.* its perfect but for complex types you might want to improve this implementation.

It's generic and standard container compatible. You could count anything iterable.

Comment: For small and known "contiguous" "alphabet" (as digit/ascii alphabet), `std::array<std::size_t, N>` might even replace `std::map`.

Comment: Note: I originally wanted to find a duplicate of this question; didn't find one generic enough or valuable enough. This is why I wrote this answer. Now, I think there is [a lot of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+counting+occurences) which could be closed as duplicate of _this_ one. As the author of this answer I'm not objective enough to do it.

Comment: @Jarod42 It could be done with specialization: `occurrences<42, ?>(/*...*/)` returning a `std::array</*...*/, 42>` and `occurrences(/*...*/)` a `std::map`. `?` = _starting point_, like `'a'` for counting in `[a..z]`.

Comment: the answer would even be more duplicatable if you added a note on `map`s elements being sorted

Comment: Why do you use `typename` on this line `std::map<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type, std::size_t> result;`?

Comment: @Mihai good question. You'll find the answer (and a bit more) here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/5470596. Short answer: because _I_ want the compiler to _parse_ `std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type` as a type (it could be a value, it doesn't know).

Comment: That is amazing! Thank you! I referenced your solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54479308/5252007), on a question I literally asked two hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to count occurrences of strings. STL container map is useful for this purpose. Following is example code.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<map> 
#include<string> 
#include<vector>                   

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> arrayString;
  std::map<std::string, int> counter;  
  std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it;

  arrayString.push_back("Hello");
  arrayString.push_back("World");
  arrayString.push_back("Hello");
  arrayString.push_back("Around");
  arrayString.push_back("the");
  arrayString.push_back("World");  

  // Counting logic
  for(std::string strVal : arrayString)
  {        
    it = counter.find(strVal);
    if(it != counter.end())
      it->second += 1; // increment count
    else    
      counter.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>(strVal, 1)); // first occurrence
  }

  // Results
  for(std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = counter.begin(); it != counter.end(); ++it)  
    std::cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

More compact way to write the counting logic is :

```
  // Counting logic
  for(std::string strVal : arrayString)
  {
    ++counter[strVal]; // first time -> init to 0 and increment
  }
```

Comment: You could simplify your code using [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) as I did: it creates and zero-initializes values for unknown keys.