# Sort a vector of vectors and count frequencies of unique occurences using the standard library

Tags: c++, sorting, count, unique, std

Given a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`:

- I want to output a **sorted** `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`
- that contains only **unique** `std::vector<int>`
- as well as the frequency (i.e., **count**) of these unique `std::vector<int>`

**My question is twofold:**

- how can I efficiently achieve this relying only on the standard library?
- what is causing the code below to perform poorly?

**I tried the following:**

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int>> responseVectors 
{
    { 2,  3,  2 },
    { 3,  2,  3 }, 
    { 3,  2,  3 }, 
    { 3,  3,  3 }, 
    { 1,  2,  3 }, 
    { 1,  2,  3 }, 
    { 1,  2,  3 }, 
    { 2,  1,  2 }, 
    { 0,  1,  2 }, 
    { 2,  3,  2 },
    { 3,  2,  3 }, 
    { 3,  2,  3 }, 
    { 3,  3,  3 }, 
    { 1,  2,  3 }, 
    { 1,  2,  3 }, 
    { 1,  2,  3 }, 
    { 2,  1,  2 }, 
    { 0,  1,  2 }
};

std::vector<std::vector<int>> uniqueResponseVectors;
uniqueResponseVectors.reserve(responseVectors.size());

std::sort(responseVectors.begin(), responseVectors.end());
std::unique_copy(responseVectors.begin(), responseVectors.end(), std::back_inserter(uniqueResponseVectors));

std::vector<int> freqTotal;
freqTotal.reserve(uniqueResponseVectors.size());

for(auto&& vector : uniqueResponseVectors)
{
    int count = std::count(responseVectors.begin(), responseVectors.end(), vector);
    freqTotal.push_back(count);
}
```

And the output should be:

```cpp
for(auto&& vector : uniqueResponseVectors)
{
    for(auto&& value : vector)
    {
        std::cout << "\t" << value << "\t";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
}

// Printed result for the `uniqueResponseVectors`:
//
//    0               1               2
//    1               2               3
//    2               1               2
//    2               3               2
//    3               2               3
//    3               3               3

// Similarly for the `freqTotal`:
//
//    2
//    6
//    2
//    2
//    4
//    2
```

**Additional context:**

- when I tried the code above against a larger dataset (i.e., `responseVectors` with a size of 100000 and 12 as the size of each `std::vector<int>`), it was slow.
- I also tried to manipulate `responseVectors` directly by calling `std::unique` and `erase()` on it, in order avoid creating a copy. Then I used an iterator loop to `std::count` how many times a unique `std::vector<int>` occurs. However, this proved even slower.

Comment: if you use a `map` instead of vector you get what you want for free. Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54476881/how-to-apply-the-concept-of-counting-occurrences-on-strings-variables-in-c (question is slightly different but the answer is a perfect match)

Comment: what makes your solution slow compared to using a map is that you are traversing the input several times, when you use a map you just insert the elements

Comment: @user463035818 Can you please elaborate in an answer? I appreciate the input, but not sure how to switch to using a `map`.

Comment: did you look at the link above? I could not write a better answer than given there

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed the link. I am checking the answer (i.e., https://stackoverflow.com/a/54477263/5252007) right now!

Comment: actually I would flag your question as a duplicate. I didnt do it, because then your question would get closed immediately. If you read the answer and it did solve your problem, I think you could also flag your own question as a duplicate of the other one

Comment: I am trying that implementation right now. If it solves my problem, I will write an answer below explaining why, provide a link to @YSC solution and flag it. Thanks!

Comment: @Mihai It is good you're using STL, but your question has far more to do with using the proper data structure(s).  A map, hash table, etc. should have been the choice, and given that, you have `std::map`, `std::unordered_map`, etc.

Comment: Wow! What I just learned is fantastic; made my day! Thanks for your suggestions @user463035818 and @PaulMcKenzie!

Comment: If you want to have unique elements and keep the same spirit of the vector, you can use `std::set`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to apply the concept of counting occurrences on strings variables in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54476881/how-to-apply-the-concept-of-counting-occurrences-on-strings-variables-in-c)

Comment: always glad to help. `std::map` already made my day several times ;). Just beware that performance wise there are usage patterns where `std::vector` still beats `std::map` (just consider the different complexity of their methods to insert, sort, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [user463035818](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/user463035818) pointed me to an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54477263/5252007) by [YSC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5470596/ysc)
- and [PaulMcKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3133316/paulmckenzie) further iterated on the importance of picking the proper data structure(s)

Based on this input, I tried to particularize the solution provided by [YSC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5470596/ysc) to my case, in order to better understand what is going on. It boils down to using `std::map` which is a [*sorted associative container*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

```cpp
std::map<std::vector<int>, int> SortAndCountOccurences(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vectors)
{
    std::map<std::vector<int>, int> result;

    std::for_each(vectors.begin(), vectors.end(), [&result](auto const& vector) {
            ++result[vector]; 
    });

    return result;
}
```

With the following usage:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int>> responseVectors 
{
    { 2,  3,  2 },
    { 3,  2,  3 }, 
    { 3,  2,  3 }, 
    { 3,  3,  3 }, 
    { 1,  2,  3 }, 
    { 1,  2,  3 }, 
    { 1,  2,  3 }, 
    { 2,  1,  2 }, 
    { 0,  1,  2 }, 
    { 2,  3,  2 },
    { 3,  2,  3 }, 
    { 3,  2,  3 }, 
    { 3,  3,  3 }, 
    { 1,  2,  3 }, 
    { 1,  2,  3 }, 
    { 1,  2,  3 }, 
    { 2,  1,  2 }, 
    { 0,  1,  2 }
};

std::map<std::vector<int>, int> sortedVectors = SortAndCountOccurences(responseVectors);
```

Which will output:

```cpp
for(auto&& vector : sortedVectors)
{
    for(auto&& value : vector.first)
    {
        std::cout << "\t" << value << "\t";
    }

    std::cout << "-> x" << vector.second << " times" << "\n";
}

//    0               1               2       -> x2 times
//    1               2               3       -> x6 times
//    2               1               2       -> x2 times
//    2               3               2       -> x2 times
//    3               2               3       -> x4 times
//    3               3               3       -> x2 times
```

**Note:** The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54477263/5252007) by [YSC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5470596/ysc) can be generalized to *anything iterable*.

Comment: Better use range-for instead of `std::for_each()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! What would be the advantage of a range-for?

Comment: Range-for is simpler than `std::for_each()` with lambda, it doesn't rely so much on the compiler to inline everything, and it allows you to use `break`, `return` and other normal flow-control. In addition, it's part of the core language instead of the standard library.

Comment: `std::for_each` is great whet you have a range (couple of begin/end iterators). range-for is great whet you have a collection (container, array, ...). This is a style issue, nothing serious here.

Comment: @YSC When the Range TS is finally available, one can trivially adapt any iterator-pait for use with range-for, making `std::for_each()` pretty obsolete.