# How do I set a char to a function? I am confused with the syntax... set <char> max_freq(map<char, int> frequency)

Tags: c++

Hi I have no idea how set works when I set `<char> (Function(map<char ,int>...)`
Edit :

```
//Set map
map<char, int> frequency;
```

Secondly:

```
map<char, int> count_chars(const string input) {
  // Given a map
  map<char, int> frequency;    
  // Populate it with the count of each character in the input
  //for loop to populate plus count
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      frequency[input[i]]++;
  }

  return frequency;
}
```

Third:

```
//Find highest occurence of character
char max_freq(map<char, int> frequency) {
  int key = 0;
  for (pair<char, int> elements : frequency){
     // highest = element.first;
      if(key <= elements.second){
          key = elements.second;
          highest = elements.first;
      }
  }
  return highest;
}
```

Lastly :

```
//I added set<char> s into the code below and it solved the syntax error. Any better solutions?
enter code here
// Below is what I wrote, I am supposed to find max occurrences of the character but I think I do not understand the syntax.
set<char> max_freq(map<char, int> frequency)
{
    char high;
    int key = 0;
    for (pair<char, int> elements : frequency)
    {
        if (key <= elements.second)
        {
            key = elements.second;
            high = elements.first;
            frequency[high];
        }
    }
    return frequency;
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> Map.cpp:117:12: error: could not convert 'frequency' from
>   'std::map' to 'std::set'
>        return frequency;

Comment: Where is `frequency` coming from and what does it look like, can you please update the code?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. `frequency[high]` doesn't have any effect so probably doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Hi guys i just did my edit, sorry I am new to this asking on the forums really sorry on showing only a portion.

Comment: You want your function to return a set object, but you return a map object. Hence the error. What are you trying to achieve anyway?

Comment: @Ayxan I am confused as to why the question is set in such a way that i have to create another set object to return it. I am trying to return a set of characters that have the same maximum occurence.

Comment: a `map` is not a `set`. You would get a similar error with `std::string foo() { return 1.0; }`. Nothing special about `set` or `map` with this regard

Comment: @OpkkoLim If you are trying to *return a set* then your function should be `set<char> max_freq(map<char, int> frequency)`. Obviously that function must *make a set and return it*. Something that your function does not try to do.

Comment: Okay i got it guys Finally understood what's wrong, map is map and it creates map objects, set is a set and it creates set objects they are different data types.

Comment: @OpkkoLim OK good, any problems with the implementation then ask another question.

Comment: Side note: You're doing _a lot_ of unecessary copies...

Comment: Your function can be simplified by taking advantage of the fact that a `std::map` stores sorted elements and does not allow duplicates.

Comment: john noted! But I think I'm good with the implementation :D  
andreee sorry I don't really know what information I need to paste there so I just put everything inside!!
Mihai Noted! I will consider thinking about that!!
user463035818 
and 
Ayxan Thanks for the replies those comments really answered my syntax question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your function signature:

```
set<char> max_freq(map<char, int> frequency)
```

What this signature is saying is:

"`max_freq` is a function, which takes an object of type `map<char, int>` by value and returns an object of type `set<char>`".

This means the type of the object you return must be `set<char>` or it must be implicitly convertible to that type. But you are returning an object of the type `map<char, int>`, which is not valid. Either change the signature to fit your needs, or make an object of compatible type and return it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your function appears to be the fact that there is no implicit conversion from `std::map<char, int>`(i.e., what you return) to `std::set<char>` (i.e., the function return type).

If you are interested in counting, you can use the following approach that takes advantage of the `std::map` data structure properties. You can also extend this to count whatever you need (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54481338/5252007 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54481338/5252007).

Here is an example:

```
#include "map"
#include "iostream"


std::map<char, int> max_freq(const std::string& input)
{
    std::map<char, int> frequency;

    for (auto&& character : input)
    {
        ++frequency[character];
    }

    return frequency;
}


int main() {

    auto result = max_freq("abaabc");

    for(auto&& freq : result)
    {
        std::cout << freq.first << " : " << freq.second << "\n";        
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a : 3
b : 2
c : 1
```

Comment: interesting variation, Why would you put ++frequency instead of frequency[character]++ ?

Comment: I doesn't really matter. Some argue that `++i` is faster than `++i` (check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/1812990/5252007). I haven't looked at it, but my guess is that the compiler will generate the same assembly code.

Comment: I think it matters at some point since ++variable means it will take the value of variable before it increments while variable++ means it take the incremented value of the variable.

Comment: @OpkkoLim of course it does, but I think not in this particular example.

Answer (score -1):

```
set<char> max_freq(map<char, int> frequency) // the return type of the function is 'set<char>'
{
    /*Logic Code*/

    return frequency; // frequency is 'map<char, int>' not 'set<char> '
}
```